# How i can get one page password to another page using imacros

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

First page text field ID `name:otp`. Second page ID name:"705742" (Number)(change this number randomly). How i can paste first page password in second page.
First page imacros code is:()

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:password ATTR=ID:otp CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
```

But My question is how i can paste to other page if there is no ID:otp? That page ID name:"705742" (Number)(change this number randomly).

Is there any way to paste first page password using "Text Field Name"= "Enter OTP"?

[First page Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YON7.jpg)
[Second page Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THzXs.jpg)

Comment: Try to use [relative positioning](http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction#Extract_with_relative_Positioning) after making an anchor on the DIV element with ‘Enter OTP’ text. (FYI: you should provide html-codes in a text (or code) format in order to count on more concrete answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.. The below code will enter values irrespective of ID name,(but Attribute should be ID),also ensure that each page is having only one password field..

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:password ATTR=ID:* CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
```

Comment: Did you see the First page Code and Second Page Code?

Comment: What's the 'TAG' that you used in the second page? ..  Also I suggest you to use the Xpath of the password field in the second page.. use the Tag like below 
    
TAG XPATH="//form[@id='demo']/fieldset[1]/ol/li[1]/input[1]" CONTENT={{!VAR2}}